# How to find product name or info from image ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, web-services, scanning

How can I find a product name or info by using image. just like RedLaser app is doing, you just snap the product and it will analyze and give you name and also give related products.
Is there any web service which can help me on this.

I take a picture of my LCD

RedLaser do rest:
Performing: Analyzing image

Result: Computer Monitor

How?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_recognition ... not simple as you might think

Comment: @pe60t0 YES I know.. Thats why I ask for webService. Which make these things easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try image recognition, to achieve your goal.

You may find some help to start it, from following links.

- http://face.com/
- http://www.iqengines.com/
- http://intopii.com/
- https://www.iqengines.com/

Comment: Thanks... The last one seems use ful.. but as i am starter. so use in storyboard with arc is hard.. but trying thanks...